# How to get the project id in IBM Watson?

Tags: ibm-watson

How do I get the project ID of my project in IBM Watson so that I access a data source?

Answer (score 1):

This is documented here :  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.0?topic=lib-watson-studio-python

```
from ibm_watson_studio_lib import access_project_or_space
wslib = access_project_or_space()
project_name = wslib.here.get_name()
wslib.show(project_name)
project_id = wslib.here.get_ID()
wslib.show(project_id)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fezyK.png)

The old project-lib has been deprecated. See Deprecation Announcement https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.0?topic=notebook-using-project-lib-python-deprecated

Answer (score -2):

In the project homepage url, the project id is the alphanumeric string just after the '/proj/". Copy it and use it as the project id.

Comment: In general you should reference where you found this answer so that others can see the original source.